# Efficient way to create a key-value data structure with repeating data in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

**What is the most efficient data structure for a key-value storage where the value repeats across multiple keys?**

I'm trying to efficiently search a Japanese dictionary (JMDict). By default, the XML turned into associative array consumes a lot of memory with tons of entries. To search I need to loop over the entire array, which isn't very efficient.

The dictionary is structured in such a way that I can't just take a single key and assign it to the dictionary entry. Mutliple Kanji/Hiragana keys map to the same entry.

```
<entry>
    <ent_seq>1000320</ent_seq>
    <k_ele>
        <keb>彼処</keb>
        <ke_inf>&rK;</ke_inf>
    </k_ele>
    <k_ele>
        <keb>彼所</keb>
        <ke_inf>&rK;</ke_inf>
    </k_ele>
    <r_ele>
        <reb>あそこ</reb>
        <re_pri>ichi1</re_pri>
    </r_ele>
    <r_ele>
        <reb>あすこ</reb>
    </r_ele>
    <r_ele>
        <reb>かしこ</reb>
    </r_ele>
    <r_ele>
        <reb>アソコ</reb>
        <re_nokanji/>
    </r_ele>
    <r_ele>
        <reb>あしこ</reb>
        <re_inf>&ok;</re_inf>
    </r_ele>
    <r_ele>
        <reb>あこ</reb>
        <re_inf>&ok;</re_inf>
    </r_ele>
    <sense>
        <pos>&pn;</pos>
        <xref>どこ・1</xref>
        <xref>ここ・1</xref>
        <xref>そこ・1</xref>
        <misc>&uk;</misc>
        <s_inf>place physically distant from both speaker and listener</s_inf>
        <gloss>there</gloss>
        <gloss>over there</gloss>
        <gloss>that place</gloss>
        <gloss>yonder</gloss>
        <gloss>you-know-where</gloss>
    </sense>
    <sense>
        <stagr>あそこ</stagr>
        <stagr>あすこ</stagr>
        <stagr>アソコ</stagr>
        <pos>&n;</pos>
        <misc>&col;</misc>
        <misc>&uk;</misc>
        <gloss>genitals</gloss>
        <gloss>private parts</gloss>
        <gloss>nether regions</gloss>
    </sense>
    <sense>
        <pos>&n;</pos>
        <xref>あれほど</xref>
        <misc>&uk;</misc>
        <s_inf>something psychologically distant from both speaker and listener</s_inf>
        <gloss>that far</gloss>
        <gloss>that much</gloss>
        <gloss>that point</gloss>
    </sense>
</entry>
```

If I were to make a key for each Kanji/Hiragana as above and copy paste the same entry, the memory use would be enormous.

My current thoughts is to have an array with all the dictionary values. Then have another associative array with the Kanji/Hiragana values mapped to the index of the dictionary array.

Is there a more efficient data structure to create key-val stores where multiple keys map to the same value?

Comment: Convert it to a database schema, then store it in a db and have _that_ do your searching? Doing this in PHP itself is not what PHP was ever designed for.

Comment: For in-memory storage you're headed in the right direction. The correct datastructure is called a _DAWG_ or [Directed Acyclic Word Graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) which can be either an array of arrays or an object in php. I'd personally recommend using an object because of referency bits in the traversal logic.

Comment: To be honest, we would need code-wise concrete examples of how you would have your search method look like.

Comment: I'll just go for the double array setup. One array for the data, another for the indexes. Seems like that's the easiest method. Converting it into a database sounds like more work. Not sure how objects would deal with data duplication, seems the same for me.